# Changing CSS via JS only first array item is affected

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I am trying to change the CSS `display` property of an object when my player rocket collides with a planet, when the player is near the planet, some text shows, when it flies away, the text vanishes.

As far as i can tell it might be a problem in how i am resetting the item to `display: none`

Removing the `else if` entirely shows the correct items when i navigate near them.

```
this.planetArr          = function(x, y, r, c, n){
    this.planet.push        ( new Game.World.Planet(x, y, r, c, n))
};

var item                = null;
var plyr                = this.player;

this.update             = function(){
    var p = this.planet.length - 1;

    for(p; p > -1; --p){
        var plnt = this.planet[p];

        if(this.vector.checkCollision(plyr, plnt)) {
            item = document.querySelector('#' + plnt.name);
            item.style.display = 'block';
        } else if (item) {
            item.style.display = 'none';
            item = null;
        }
    }
};
```

Only the first item in my array works as intended, the rest appear to skip the style change to `display: block` and go straight for the `display: none` reset.

Comment: Put this line before `if` condition and try. `item = document.querySelector('#' + plnt.name);`

Comment: That was it :) thank you!